# What is the difference b/w the two async/await functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
const displaySymbols = async (symbols) => {
  const sym = await Promise.all(symbols.map(s => {
    // createEl return a promise
    return createEl(s)
  }))
  return sym
}

const displaySymbols = async (symbols) => {
  const sym = await Promise.all(symbols.map(async s => {
    return await createEl(s)
  }))
  return sym
}
```

The results are same, without `Promise.all`, `sym` would be always a promise array, no matter `createEl` is await-ed or not, then is it necessary to use async function as map method?

P.S. The code is just a demo.

Comment: No, it's not necessary to use `async`/`await` syntax in the map function, but when your function does something asynchronous that should be waited for it needs to return a promise.

Comment: @Bergi, I didn't get it, in the map function,createEl does things asynchrously,

Comment: And `createEl()` does return a promise - so you should `return` that promise. You don't need `async`/`await` for anything.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks, I just saw some other people's code like the second function,that makes me confused.

Comment: Those are the people without a clue :-) And of course it could be further simplified to `function displaySymbols(symbols) { return Promise.all(symbols.map(createEl)); }`

Answer (score 1):

The second one is superflous. Its like:

```
Promise.resolve( new Promise() )
```